# Is there a reason why I cant get the values from the following two elements?

Tags: c#, xml, xslt, sharepoint-2010

I have code that submits a query and the results in xml format then get assigned to a string variable "tmp" I then provide this variable as a xml input to a function that uses a separate xslt stylesheet to convert the xml results into html.

### XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?> 
<Results>
<Exchange>
<OLO>LSMIT</OLO>
<Name>Mitcham</Name>
</Exchange>
<Checks>
<Check id="adsl">
<Linecode>GGEZ</Linecode>
<Linespeed>2048</Linespeed>
<Matched>Address</Matched>
<Provider>BT ADSL</Provider>
<Type>BT xDSL</Type>
<Updated>2010-08-17</Updated>
</Check>
</Checks>
</Results>
```

### XSLT Stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
<body>
<p>You are connected to the <b>
<xsl:for-each select="Results/Exchange">
<xsl:value-of select="Name"/>
</xsl:for-each>
</b> telephone exchange</p>
<br/>

<p>According to <b>
<xsl:for-each select="Results/Checks/Check">
<xsl:value-of select="Provider"/>
</xsl:for-each>
</b>, houses at your postcode should be able to suppor the following:</p>
<br/>

<table>
<tr>
<td>
<img src="/img/tick_BGAvailabilityChecker.png"></img>  
</td>
<td>
up to 
<xsl:for-each select="Results/Checks/Check">
<xsl:value-of select="Linespeed"/>
</xsl:for-each> 
</td>
</tr>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
```

I cant display the evalues of the following elements:

```
<Linecode>
<Linespeed>
<Matched>
```

I can however display the following elements just fine:

```
<Provider>
<Type>
<Updated>
```

All the above are childs of the  element

Its a weird one, The question is why I can't I display the values of the Linecode, Linespeed, Matched elemets?

I have spent far too much time on this without being able to firgure out what some elements are displaying and others not. Any ideas will be greatly appreciated,

Here is the code I wrote to submit the query and store the xml results to a string variable "tmp":

```
void cmdSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
//Variable declarations
string user = "PRIVATE";
string pass = "PRIVATE";
string phone = TextBox1.Text;
string postcode = TextBox2.Text;
string buildnum = TextBox3.Text;
string check = "adsl";
string option = "adsllinecheck";
string outputformat = "xml";

string url = String.Format("http://api.samknows.com/checker.do?user={0}&pass={1}&phone=
{2}&postcode={3}&buildingnum={4}&checks={5}&options{6}&output{7}", user, pass, phone, 
postcode, buildnum, check, option, outputformat);
Uri uri = new Uri(url);

 string data = "field-keywords=ASP.NET 3.5";

 if (uri.Scheme == Uri.UriSchemeHttp)
 {
 HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(uri);
 request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Post;
 request.ContentLength = data.Length;
 request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

 StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream());
 writer.Write(data);
 writer.Close();
 HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

 StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
 string tmp = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

After debuggin it seams that the  elements are not being returned. However when I simply copy the query string into a browser the results in xml do display the elements in question.

Is there anything different that I can do in the way I submit the query to ensure all elements are returned?

Thanks

Comment: Please provide a valid .xml input.

Comment: The input sample you posted is not well-formed, it has a opening `<Exchange>` tag but no matching closing tag.

Comment: Hi, I have edited the XML. Above it is a valid xml. Thanks

Comment: Your .xsl is also not well formed, as well as the output it produces.

Comment: The xml are results that I get from submitting a query. So I have no control of how its displayed. I made a mistake earlier in not including the closing </Exchnage> tag. The using the xslt stylesheet I can select which element values to display, but there are three that simply do not get displayed (Linespeed, Linecode, Matched) no matter what I do. Its pretty frustrating now. Hope you might be able to shed some light into this. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there was nothing wrong major wrong with the code. After ispecting the query string:

```
string url = String.Format("http://api.samknows.com/checker.do?user={0}&pass={1}&phone=
{2}&postcode={3}&buildingnum={4}&checks={5}&options{6}&output{7}"
```

I noticed that the assignement operator (=) was missing from the options and output parameters. After adding those everything worked perfectly....

Silly mistake, Problems Solved in the end!

Thanks to all anyways for all he suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question theoretically. Yes there are plenty of reasons and your xslt transform is not one of them. The output of your xslt applied to your xml is this :

```
<html>
   <body>
      <p>
         You are connected to the <b>Mitcham</b> telephone exchange

      </p><br><p>
         According to <b>BT ADSL</b>, houses at your postcode should be able to suppor the following:

      </p><br><table>
         <tr>
            <td><img src="/img/tick_BGAvailabilityChecker.png"></td>
            <td>
               up to
               2048
            </td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

Which is is contrast with your claims of being unable to display the Linespeed element. The error is at some other part of your code which you do not show.

Comment: You are corrent everything gets displayed as required its just the value of the <Linespeed> that does not get displayed. Instead of displaying the value "2048"  I get nothing. Now this happens also with the <Linecode> and <Matched> elements as well, which is weird! The rest of the code is just 1. a string to contains the query to be submitted, 2. A function that handles the transformation using the xslt stylesheet. What I dont understand is how I can get some values to be displayed and other not. I know the code is correct otherwise I would not be able to display any values.

Comment: @DanielPerez As I said, the xslt part of your algorithm is correct. Your problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: Looks like Its back to the drawing board then, and more research!. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @DanielPerez Np. Just either close the question or select this as an answer.

Comment: After debuggin it seems that the results of the query are for some reason not returning the <Linespeed><Linecode><Matched> elements. I have added the code I use to perfomr the query and bring back the results.